# С++ как записать массив из функций

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func(int mus[3]){
int numb = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
numb += i;
return(numb);
}

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
cout << func(mus[i]);/* вот здесь компилятор ругается на mus[i] как правильно записать*/
cin.get(); cin.get();
     }
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что домашние задания надо делать самому

Comment: да вы правы но мне нужна помощь конкретно по этому вопросу так как затрудняюсь сделать

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ru.SO! Формат нашего ресурса несколько отличается от форматов форумов. Пожалуйста, переформулируйте Ваш вопрос, чтобы он отражал проблему, с которой Вы столкнулись при решении данной задачи. Вам может быть полезна [справка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - в ней описано, какие вопросы приветствуются на данном сайте.

Comment: @Roma Abubakir А как вы хотите его записать?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow хочу получить сохраненные данные из func то есть numb

Comment: @Roma Abubakir Но numb - это не массив. Поэтому непонятно, для чего вообще предназначена эта функция.

Comment: Начнем с того, что тут вовсе нет **массива из функций** (массива адресов функций), а есть функция, которая получает в качестве аргумента массив. Вот и напишите в main массив из 3-х элементов и передайте его в свою функцию.

Comment: @avp Спасибо за помощь понял ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int func(int mus[3])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            sum += mus[i];
        return sum;
    }
void main()
{
    int mas[3] = { 3, 2, 1 };
    cout << func(mas);
}
```

Comment: Правильно было бы еще передавать размер массива в функцию, чтобы функция могла иметь дело с массивами любого размера.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow , Вообще да, но в данном случае я просто исправил код парня. Дальше пусть сам немного подумает.